# Unable to update data with Laravel does not show any error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update my data with Laravel. I'm able to create, read, delete the data but somehow i cannot update my data. I already checked my controller,model,route and view but i don't think there's any typo or anything. It only redirects to it's index page without being updated although i have entered new input. There's no error message at all so it makes me more confused of what's wrong because i really don't know why.

**Route for edit and update**

```
Route::get('contact/{contact}/edit', 'ContactController@edit');
Route::post('contact/update','ContactController@update');
```

**Controller with edit and update function**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Contact;
use DB;

public function edit($kode_kontak){
        $contact = DB::table('contact')->where('kode_kontak',$kode_kontak)->get();
        return view('contact.edit',['contact' => $contact]);
    }

public function update(Request $request){
        DB::table('contact')->where('kode_kontak',$request->kode_kontak)->update([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'telepon' => $request->telepon,
        ]);
        return redirect('contact');
    }
```

**Model**

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $table = 'contact';

    protected $fillable = [
        'kode_kontak',
        'kode_pegawai',
        'email',
        'telepon'
        
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'kode_kontak';
}
```

**View of edit.blade.php**

```
<div id="contact">
    <h2>Edit Contact</h2>
    @foreach($contact as $p)
        <form action="/contact/update" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_contact" class="control-label">Kode Kontak</label>
            <input type="text" name="kode_kontak" id="kode_kontak" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->kode_kontak}}" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_pegawai" class="control-label">Kode Pegawai</label>
            <input type="text" name="kode_pegawai" id="kode_pegawai" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->kode_pegawai}}" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->email}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telepon" class="control-label">Telepon</label>
            <input type="text" name="telepon" id="telepon" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->telepon}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Simpan">
        </div>
    </form>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: check your log file inside the storage folder. Damn sure you would have log there,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update route is using the wrong "verb" and url. If you take a look at Laravel's [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers) you can see the different actions and route names available for editing, updating, deleting etc. when creating a "CRUD" controller.

You can see the route for an "update" action and its "verb".

Change your routes to

```
Route::get('contact/{contact}/edit', 'ContactController@edit')->name('contact.edit');
Route::patch('contact/{contact}','ContactController@update')->name('contact.update');
```

Or if you want to add a complete CRUD controller use the short form:

```
Route::resource('contact', 'ContactController');
```

This will create all required routes in one convenient line of code. Use `php artisan route:list` to check all routes.

HTTP forms only support GET and POST methods, Laravel uses `@method()` in blade to add the other verbs (put,patch,delete):

**Edit:**

your form uses `disabled` attributes on some `<input>`s. Those values will *not* be sent along with your request. Here's an updated `edit.blade.php`:

- `disabled` attributes have been swapped with `readonly`.
- The `action` uses Laravel's [RouteModelBinding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding)
- Removed the `@foreach` since you only have *one* item to be edited

**edit.blade.php**:

```
<div id="contact">
    <h2>Edit Contact</h2>
    <form action="{{ route('contact.update', ['contact' => $contact]) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('patch')
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_contact" class="control-label">Kode Kontak</label>
            <input type="text" name="kode_kontak" id="kode_kontak" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->kode_kontak}}" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_pegawai" class="control-label">Kode Pegawai</label>
            <input type="text" name="kode_pegawai" id="kode_pegawai" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->kode_pegawai}}" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->email}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telepon" class="control-label">Telepon</label>
            <input type="text" name="telepon" id="telepon" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->telepon}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Simpan">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Since it's using RouteModelBinding you can change your `update()` method to:

```
public function update(Request $request, Contact $contact)
{
    $contact->update([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'telepon' => $request->telepon,
    ]);
    return redirect('contact');
}
```

Laravel will know what Contact `$contact` is

Comment: this is helpful but it still does not update the data..

Comment: That's due to the fact that, as I just now realized, your two first `<input>` fields have a `disabled` attribute. Disabled fields will not be sent along the request, so `$request->kode_kontak` is `null` and your `where` clause does not return anything. Change your `disabled` attributes to `readonly` attributes if you don't want the user to make any changes but still send the values in your request

Comment: it doesn't work too.. i checked with the `dd($request->all()) ` but it only shows email and telepon

Comment: I updated my answer with some more adjustments, feel free to ask if something seems unclear or doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you loop your contact to produce a form for each one of them with the same input name, id,... which is the wrong approach.
my suggestion to you :
Route for edit and update

```
Route::get('contact/{contact}/edit', 'ContactController@edit');
Route::post('contact/{contact}/edit', 'ContactController@update');
```

Controller with edit and update function

```
public function edit(Contact $contact){

  return view('contact.edit',compact('contact'));
}

public function update(Request $request,Contact $contact){

        $contact->update([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'telepon' => $request->telepon,
        ]);

        return redirect('contact');
    }
```

and of course, you will update edit.blade.php

```
<div id="contact">
    <h2>Edit Contact</h2>
    @foreach($contact as $p)
        <form action="/contact/{{ $p->id }}/update" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_contact" class="control-label">Kode Kontak</label>
            <input type="text" name="kode_kontak" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->kode_kontak}}" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kode_pegawai" class="control-label">Kode Pegawai</label>
      <input type="text" name="kode_pegawai" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->kode_pegawai}}" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->email}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telepon" class="control-label">Telepon</label>
            <input type="text" name="telepon" class="form-control" value="{{ $p->telepon}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Simpan">
        </div>
    </form>
    @endforeach
</div>
```